# How to remove the cancel button from the billing address edit form?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, billing-address

As per the title, how do I remove the cancel button from the billing address edit form ? 
The button is highlighted on the screenshot attached bellow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you know the basics of creating a module.

1.In your custom module, create ***Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js***

```
var config= {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/actions.html': 'Ananta_RemoveCancel/template/billing-address/actions.html',
        }
    }
}
```

2.Now create template file, ***Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/actions.html***

```
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button class="action action-update"
                type="button"
                click="updateAddress">
            <span translate="'Update'"/>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Done, now cancel button from the billing-address form will be removed.

Comment: Had to update one path (`Ananta_RemoveCancel` to plugin name)  a bit, but the answer is good, thank you.